# Как записать в файл значения переменных типа integer

Tags: python, файлы

Написал программу на `Python`. Считывает из `file.txt` очередное целое число, обрабатывает его по заданным правилам и выдает на экран результат - пару целых чисел. Результат обработки надо записать в файл для дальнейшей обработки. Извините, я не программист, помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: 1. Что значит "переменных типа integer"? Для питона эти слова не имеют смысла.

2. Нужно записать целые значения. Если в текстовом формате -- то print.

Comment: Задачу уточните. В какой файл: в бинарный или в текстовой файл?

Comment: Для Python 2.7 это работает только для переменной, имеющей тип str, а мне надо записать по итогу каждой итерации пару целых чисел (int), что в предложенном коде не получается. Очевидно, надо их перевести в стоковый вид. Пробовал изменять тип вручную: 12345 --> '12345\n' , запись получается и главное потом из файла считывается число! Каков код для этой операции?

Comment: Это Вы о чём?

     print >>f, 12345

Это?

Comment: alexlz, поясните, пожалуйста, что исполняет код print >>f, 12345 ??

Comment: В python2 оператор print выводит в файл преобразованные в текст значения параметров. Если указан параметр `>>f`, то он означает вывод в открытый файл f, иначе -- в stdout. Если в конце списка параметров print нет запятой, то строка завершается переводом строки (в *nix, в виндах -- `\r\n`)

         file_1 = open("file.txt", "w")
         print >>f, 12345
         f.close()

Выполните и посмотрите, что будет в file.txt

Comment: Правильно, в file.txt будет записана строка 12345, но это не есть решение проблемы, поскольку в строку print >>f,.... вы своей рукой вколотили число 12345. Проблема: в результате работы программы некой переменной Х было присвоено int значение = 12345. А теперь необходимо это число записать в file.txt   КАК это выполнить программно???

Comment: @Fomich, а разве не ясно?

    a=888888
    a+=2
    print >> f, a

Вы бы почитали что-нибудь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file_1 = open("file.txt", "w")
# Открываем файл "file.txt" для записи. "w" - переписать, "a" - дописать в конец.
# Всегда используем слеши вперед, даже на виндовсе
# Если такого файла нет и прав достаточно, то он создастся. Если нет - будет ошибка.
# Проверить наличие файла можно функцией exists(path) из os.path

file_1.write(str(51))
# Записываем сюда что-то, предварительно преобразовав в строку командой str(x)

file_1.close()
# Закрываем файл
```

Пример для второго питона, текстовые файлы. Подробности в [официальной документации](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).
Кстати в питоне нет переменных строго типа integer, питон - язык с динамической типизацией.

Comment: Питон - язык с динамической, но строгой типизацией. И в нем есть тип `int`

Comment: Ну да... Логично. Я имел ввиду, что в питоне нет конструкций типа int a = 5;, переменные преобразуются автоматически. Или, в случае с write, не автоматически...

Comment: Вообще вырезал эту фразу, чтоб народ не смущать)

Comment: @Zelta зря. Просто не все помнят/понимают, что при динамической типизации тип имеют значения, а не переменные.

Comment: Запустите код

    a=5
    print type(a)

и посмотрите, что напечатается

Comment: @mikillskegg: `type(a)` читается как «тип значения, находящегося в переменной `a`», а не «тип переменной `a`.» Это если буквоедствовать.

Comment: @drdaeman, все правильно. И тем не менее... 

Кстати, правильнее было бы говорить: тип объекта, на который ссылается переменная.